# Query a view which is created from partitioned table in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table called *customers*.
I have created a view from *customers* table as below and its called *customers_view* (there are more constraints in **where** clause which I omitted here):

```
SELECT * FROM `customers`
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) > "2021-05-10"
```

Now I want to query from *customers_view* but when I write:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers_view`
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) > "2021-05-12"
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `customers_view`
WHERE DATE(_pt) > "2021-05-12"
```

It gives this error: ! **Unrecognized name:_PARTITIONTIME** (or _pt)

How I can query a view which is made from a partitioned table and have partition time in where clause?
(Both table and view has a timestamp column as well but I think some rows have 1 day gap between timestamp and _pt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the partition time in the view, you need to include it explicitly:

```
SELECT c.*, _PARTITIONTIME as pt
FROM `customers`
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) > '2021-05-10'
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, let me try then I will mark it as correct answer